# Sumif range of criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, range

I've checked different questions and answers on the site, but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I try to have a sum of values, using multiple criteria (OR): When I use, e.g.,

```
=SUM(SUMIF('2014-02'!B:B;{"value1";"Value2";"Value3"};'2014-02'!H:H))
```

it works fine.

However, the criteria can change every month (other values, more or less values, etc). When I create a cell with, e.g.,

```
=""""&AH7&""";"""&AI7&""";"""&BB7&"""";
```

the result is `"Value1";"Value2";"Value3"`.

But then I loose the braces {} and I cannot add them to the formula above without an error message. E.g. so this won't work

```
=SUM(SUMIF('2014-02'!B:B;{AA7};'2014-02'!H:H))
```

How can I make the criteria part dynamic, referencing a cell with my possblie values (range) somewhere else in the sheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to multiple an array of your summed column by an array of 0s and 1s, generated by checks for matches against your range of criteria values.

`=SUMPRODUCT('2014-02'!H:H,--ISNUMBER(MATCH('2014-02'!B:B,AH7:BB7,0)))`

Note, this would work only for equal to criteria, not greater than or less than...  Also, the cell reference can be a whole column or range, but a non-contiguous range won't work as written.